# locking on delete from parent table instead of error

Tags: oracle

I have Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0.
I have parent table t1 and t2 with foreign key which references t1(col1).
What I'm wondering is why locking is there?
Please check what I've done...

## session 1

```
SQL> create table t1(col1 char(1), primary key(col1));
Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values('1');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t1 values('2');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t1 values('3');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t1 values('4');
1 row created.
SQL> insert into t1 values('5');
1 row created.

SQL> commit;
Commit complete.


SQL> create table t2(col1 char(1), col2 char(2), foreign key(col1) references t1(col1));
Table created.

SQL> insert into t2 values('1','0');
1 row created.
SQL> commit;
Commit complete.

SQL> update t2 set col2='9';   --not committed yet!
1 row updated.
```

## session 2

```
SQL> delete from t1;    -- Lock happens here!!!
```

## session 1

```
SQL> commit;
Commit complete.
```

## session 2

```
delete from t1          -- The error occurs after I commit updating query in session 1.
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (KMS_USER.SYS_C0013643) violated - child record found
```

Could anyone explain me why this happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`delete from t1;` tries to lock the child table, T2.  If the session is waiting on the entire table lock it can't even try to delete anything yet.

This unusual locking behavior occurs because you have an [unindexed foreign key](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16508/datainte.htm#CNCPT1657).

If you create an index, `create index t2_idx on t2(col1);`, you will get the `ORA-02292` error instead of the lock.

Comment: Thanks for your advice... Is there any reference that I can read about lock mechnism?

Comment: You may want to start with the [Database Concepts manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25789/consist.htm#i5704).

Answer (score 0):

The lock is coming from your line: `insert into t2 values('1','0');` The lock does not happen when you delete from t1 in session 2.

Think about it. Once you insert this row in session 1, there is a reference from t2.col1 back to t1.col1. The foreign key has been validated at that point and Oracle knows that the '1' exists in t1. If session 2 could delete that row from t1, then session 2 would have an uncommitted row in t2 that had an invalid reference to t1, which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I've edited it... commit statement was missed. sorry, it's my fault.

Comment: Anyway, you didn't get my point... My point is why locking occurs instead of ORA_02292 which happens after commit....